# VBA - If statement that references specific text in a cell in a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build logic where if a specific cell in a specific worksheet is populated with a specific string, it skips running that sub and goes on to the next one. What I think is my closest attempt so far from some research:

```
        Dim Rng_1 As Range
        Dim x_sheet As Worksheet
        Dim Value_X

        Value_X = "<>Could not generate report for*"
        Set x_sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet_name")
        Set Rng_1 = x_sheet.Range("B8")
            If Rng_1.value = Value_X Then
           'run code
        End If
       'It should continue from here if the referenced cell did contain the string.
```

Running the above always skips the code in between regardless of how I edit the does not contain value or even if I add "else if". At this point, i'm not even sure if I'm on the right track.

[Referenced Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLuqO.png)
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your worksheet? An image would help.

Comment: Picture added of the referenced sheet. Apologies but I can't embed yet. For some detail, Column A contains the error items and column B contains the number of errors found for each item. Except for the last row that failed to generate a report. That same cell (B8) is the one I want the above to look for when determining whether to skip a sub or not.

Comment: and when exactly should it skip? (what is the string not supposed to be)?

Comment: @Rawrplus, when it is text that looks like a number.

Comment: Exactly. Each report is supposed to specify a numeric value. The only time it'll specify text is when the report fails to generate. I didn't even think about using that logic and went for having it look for a specific string instead. Definitely still much to learn on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of the data you provided, you can **reverse-engineer** your problem, to check instead, whether data is in correct format (numbers only)

```
Private Sub loop_though()

  Dim ws as Worksheet: set ws = Sheets("worksheet_name")
  Dim cell as Range
  Dim looprange as Range: Set looprange = ws.Range("B2:B10")

  For each cell in looprange
       If Not IsNumeric(cell) Then 'cell does not contain only numbers
          ' further code here
       End If
  Next cell

End Sub
```

---

Alternatively, if you insist on checking for the "`value_x`" within the cells, then this would be the solution.

```
Private Sub loop_though()

  Dim ws as Worksheet: set ws = Sheets("worksheet_name")
  Dim cell as Range
  Dim looprange as Range: Set looprange = ws.Range("B2:B10")
  Dim value_x as String: value_x = "Could not generate report for"

  For each cell in looprange
       If InStr(1, cell, value_x) <> 0 Then
          ' further code here
       End If
  Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I can definitely see myself using the first loop for this and something else I need to do with this report later on so definitely appreciate the logic there. Much more straightforward than what I made.

Comment: @Symorix [1/2] glad it helped. Also few last tips before you go. You can use `looprange` and *(depending on which approach you chosen*) `value_x `as arguments within procedure. So they can vary and procedure can be more useful. So => `Private Sub loop_through(ByVal looprange as Range, ByVal value_x as String)` and then you can reference them directly each time you invoke the Procedure, if that makes sense, eg. `loop_through(Sheets("other_sheet").Range("C3:F25"), "some other text")`

Comment: [2/2] And isntead of, let's say B8, you can use last non-empty cell in range. eg. `Dim lastrow as Long: lastrow = Sheets("Sheet Name").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` <- 2 because 2nd column, as in B. So you can set loop range to `Set looprange = Sheets("Sheet Name").Range("B2:B" & lastrow)`

Comment: I'd most likely go for the first one simply so I can can practice it and learn how exactly it works. Value_x was there only because that's how I understand VBA right now but always willing to take more pointers. Wouldn't have even known that a week ago. I'll be trying your suggestions very soon and i'll see if I can get 'em running.

Answer (score 2):

The `Like` comparison operator needs to be used when dealing with wildcards. The 'no match' for this is `Not this Like that`. You don't add the `<>` operator to produce 'does not match'.

You need `Else` if you want plan A and plan B.

```
    Value_X = "Could not generate report for*"  'removed <>
    Set x_sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet_name")
    Set Rng_1 = x_sheet.Range("B8")
    If Not Rng_1.value Like Value_X Then
       Debug.Print "msg not found"
       'run code
    Else
       Debug.Print "msg found"
       'It should continue from here if the referenced cell did contain the string.
    End If
```

fwiw, from your sample data it looks like you could also test for `IsNumeric(Rng_1.value)`.

Comment: The above worked for the most part but it was giving me a compile error when trying to put Not and Like together. I looked it up and VBA apparently doesn't like that very much. So the solution was modifying:

    `If Rng_1.value Not Like Value_X Then`
to
   `If Not Rng_1.value Like Value_X Then`

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help and even going so far as to assist with the embedding of the image above along with letting me know I could have used checking for numerical values as well. That will certainly help on this report down the line.

Comment: My bad. Sorry. I wrote that off the top of my head. You are definitely correct.

Comment: No worries at all. Your solution ended up working for what I asked for all the same. So I'm set.

Comment: @Symorix No, infact I'm a fan of it. The answer I posted is just an alternative solution *(plus I included `for each` loop as I presume you want to check every value, not just `B8`)*. Also I feel like you missunderstood my message *double negative uhh* - it reads, I will always upvote good usage of `Like`

Comment: @Rawrplus Yup. I most certainly did. Been staring at this code for too long today it seems. Starting to skim. Apologies. Still learning all this so optimizations/ what to use and not use are definitely things i want to learn before i develop bad habits.

Comment: @Symorix yeah that's a very good approach. I was very active on SO when I was learning VBA as well, a lot to be gained there :) Also, I'd recommend using https://codereview.stackexchange.com as well!

Comment: Good tip. I'll post this in once I complete it. My first attempt at VBA so I'd definitely love it to be reviewed for quality/optimization.